# find the distribution of $X$ such that $X(\omega) = \int_{0}^{1} B_s^2(\omega) ds$ where $(B_t)_{t \geq0}$ is standard Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

since for a fixed $\omega$, $B_s(\omega)$ is continuous in $s$ then $B^2_s(\omega)$ is Riemann integrable w.r.t. $s$ :

$X(\omega) = \int_{0}^{1} B_s^2(\omega) ds \implies X =  \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k = 1}^{n} B^2_{\frac{k}{n}}  =  \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k = 1}^{n} Y_k$

I would like to use the strong law of large numbers but I don't have independence of the $Y_i$'s.

I know for one that for $t \geq s$, the increments $B_t - B_s$ are independent of $B_s$, maybe we can somehow use this property here ?

Comment: I don't think that this has a nice, known distribution. See here for a derivation of the variance of the integral: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/30730/variance-of-time-integral-of-squared-brownian-motion

Comment: The distribution is known; cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784444/integral-of-wiener-squared-process/1794806#1794806