# autocorrelation of Wiener process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I don't have a background in stochastic calculus.

Question: what is the autocorrelation of the Wiener process($W_{t}$)?
$$\int_{0}^{T}W_{t}W_{t+\tau}dt=?$$

The facts I know so far are [Itô's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4%27s_lemma) and [Itô isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_isometry), but I do not know how to apply them. Also, I found a similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784444/integral-of-wiener-squared-process).

Furthermore, I did a simulation and found out that the expectation of the integral satisfies
$$\mathbb{E}\bigg{[}\int_{0}^{T}W_{t}W_{t+\tau}dt\bigg{]}=\frac{1}{2}(\tau-T)^{2}$$.

Can anyone help me figure out how to do it analytically? thank you!

Comment: For $\tau\geq0$, we have $$\mathbb{E}\left[ \int_{0}^{T}W_t W_{t+\tau}\,\mathrm{d}t\right]=\int_{0}^{T}\mathbb{E}[W_t W_{t+\tau}]\,\mathrm{d}t\qquad\text{and}\qquad\mathbb{E}[W_t W_{t+\tau}]=t.$$

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. However, autocorrelation is not a linear operator, so we cannot swap expectation into the integral.

Comment: @WzS yes, you can swap the expectation with the integral by applying [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) on the domain $[0,T]\times\Omega$.

Comment: that's correct! thank you for the clarification!